# Android application with supporting all platforms except android

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, gradle, google-play

I create application in Android Studio, and send it to Google Play Store, after time i add library "[littleprxy](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy)"(based on netty), and when it came time to send updated application in Google Play Console i see Supported platform : amd64-Linux-gpp, amd64-Windows-gpp, arm-Linux-gpp, i386-Linux-gpp, i386-MacOSX-gpp, x86_64-MacOSX-gpp, x86-Windows-gpp, and ofcourse 0 supported Android devices, but i can install apk manually, and it work fine.
How i can fix it? Maybe some parameters for gradle or manifest...
Sorry for English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LittlePrxy is written atop Netty. Netty is kind of "heavy" for Android. Most of Android devices are resource limit. memory footprint, cpu usage should be carefully treated. This is the reason why Netty doesn't support Android OS. Sure you will be able to use this lib but it is not recommended. This is why GooglePlay reports an error, because Android is not specified in the list of supported OS of this lib.

In short, you should not use LittlePrxy in your app. You should find another library.